# VB.net Addmonths

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to move Dates, i.e. Go back a month or forward a month. If I move back a month as of this month (February) to January, it holds February's last day (28th) the same if I add a month. The start Date is fine as all month's start on the 1st.

Please could anyone advise.Thanks

Vb

```
            hStartDate.Value = "2013/2/01 12:00:00 AM"
            hEndDate.Value = "2013/2/28 11:59:59 PM"


            Dim StartDate As New Date
            StartDate = hStartDate.Value
            hStartDate.Value = StartDate.AddMonths(-1)


            Dim EndDate As New Date
            EndDate = hEndDate.Value
            hEndDate.Value = EndDate.AddMonths(-1)
```

Output

```
            hStartDate.Value = "2013/01/01"
            hEndDate.Value = "2013/01/28 11:59:59 PM"
```

Comment: Is the end date *always* meant to be a month later than the start date? If so, I'd do everything through the start date: work out the end date by adding a month and then subtracting a day.

Comment: No its a chart I pull with the current month's data on Load, I then have button's to go to previous month or to the next month (Basically adding a month or removing a month from what ever month they are currently in.

Comment: you've not asked the code to get you the last date in the previous month, all you've asked is for it to remove one month from the current dates that have been explicitly set.

Comment: @user1475479: Well that's exactly what it *does* do, at the moment - it removes a month from your current end date. February 28th minus one month is January 28th. If you expected it to be January 31st, that's because you *really* want it to be "the end of the month that starts with StartDate"... which is what I'm suggesting you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the end date (after `hStartDate` is modified):

```
hEndDate.Value = New Date(hStartDate.Year, hStartDate.Month, Date.DaysInMonth(hStartDate.Year, hStartDate.Month))
```

The function `Date.DaysInMOnth()` returns the last day of a month in a year given. You could set your date like this too if you prefer:

```
hEndDate.Value = EndDate.AddMonths(-1)
hEndDate.Value.Day = Date.DaysInMonth(hStartDate.Year, hStartDate.Month)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [DevCurry](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/11/find-last-day-of-previous-month-using-c.html) it's basically taking the 1st day of the current month and removing one day thus resulting in the last day of the previous month.

```
    hStartDate.Value = "2013/2/01 12:00:00 AM"
    hEndDate.Value = "2013/2/28 11:59:59 PM"


    Dim StartDate As New Date
    StartDate = hStartDate.Value
    hStartDate.Value = StartDate.AddMonths(-1)


    Dim EndDate As New Date
    EndDate = hEndDate.Value
    hEndDate.Value = StartDate.AddDays(-1)
```